# gridview itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to add a  inside a gridview cell. More particularly, the datasource is a number between 1 and 7 and based on that number, the div needs to be of a certain background color and the text need to be a certain word. For instance, if the data is 1, the div should be yellow and the word should be sunny.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to RowDataBound

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    int value = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
    // e.Row.Cells[2] references the cell value you want to use
    if (value < 100)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.FromName("#c6efce");
    }
    if ((value >= 100) && (value < 500))
    {
        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.FromName("#ffeb9c");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The line int value = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
 most be: int value = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourFieldHere");

Answer (score 1):

You can change it on RowDataBound event of the GridView like as explained in

[GridView : Working with TemplateFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx)

or

You can specify the details in your query like

```
select 
  case when [number] = 1 then 'Sunny'
       when [number] = 2 then 'Rainy'
       end as [DisplayWord],
  case when [number] = 1 then 'Yellow'
       when [number] = 2 then 'Red'
       end as [DisplayColor]
from [YourTable]
```

and Bind it

I prefer the second method